# How to present modalViewController inside the masterViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I am doing an `iPad` app with `UISplitViewController`. I want to open a `modalViewController` in the masterViewController itself. **When I load my view controller modally, it takes a whole screen to present it.**

Here it is my code, which is in my `masterViewController`.m to present the new `viewController` modally

```
- (void)addNewContactButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    AddOrEditContact *addContact = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddOrEditContact"];
    addContact.screenMode = addMode;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:addContact];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I want to load a new `viewController` modally inside the `masterViewController.` Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need it modal? You could push it (given that there is a navigation controller) or you could use a popup.

Comment: I am showing contacts in master view. I want to add a new contact or edit a old contact.. I would like to do it in the master view itself. Bcoz design is like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't present a modal viewController over the masterViewController only, but you can add a childView controller to the masterViewController nd perform your own animation to present it

```
- (void)addiewControllerToHierarchy:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self addChildViewController:viewController];

    [self.view addSubview:frontViewController.view];

    if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(didMoveToParentViewController:)])
    {
        [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
}
```

and to remove

```
- (void)_removeViewControllerFromHierarchy:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];

    if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(removeFromParentViewController)])
    {
        [viewController removeFromParentViewController];        
    }
}
```

this example doesn't have animation and probably you need to adjust the frame of the view etc... but I hope could help you

Comment: let me know if this could help you

Comment: Yeah It helped me.. But I am waiting for some more best answer. If nothing I get, I would accept yours.

Comment: I need to handle the navigation bar of modal view controller on myself in your answer. It shows below the current view controller navigation bar.